# Missing parameter settings in Execute Pipeline in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

In ADF I have setup a master pipeline and here I have created a parameter.

In the master pipeline I have a foreach statement and it executes a child pipeline.

In the settings of the Execute Pipeline step I expected to set the value of the parameter I created in the Master pipeline, but the option is not there.

This is what I would expect to se:

[image]

Here is what it looks like in my factory:

[image]

Why can't I see that option?

Comment: If you want to pass the `@item().name` value to the child pipeline, then you need to create a parameter in child pipeline. Then, if you use execute pipeline activity to run the child pipeline from master pipeline, it appears in the settings tab as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the option that you see in the first image, `ppfoldername` is a parameter created in `child pipeline` and not in master pipeline.
- When you create a set of parameters in child pipeline, and you want to execute this child pipeline from a master pipeline, all these parameters (belonging to child pipeline) request a value to be passed from the master pipeline (which is visible in the settings tab of execute pipeline activity).
- Look at the following demonstration. I have a child pipeline with parameters called `x and y`.

[image]

- When I use `execute pipeline` activity to execute this pipeline from a master pipeline, it prompts you to give values to `x and y` parameters in the settings tab.

[image]

- So, if you want to pass your `@item().name` to the child pipeline, create the parameter inside the child pipeline. Then it will show up in the settings tab of execute pipeline activity (same as expected).